How to use `setStorage` in Polkadot JS Apps? Entries cannot be decoded after setting
I need to manually change the storage entry of a storage map which does not have a setter function. Unfortunately, after calling setStorage($STORAGE_KEY, $NEW_VALUE) the corresponding storage cannot be decoded anymore. So there seems to be a flaw in my approach.
Say I have a storage map with encoded partial key 0x1da53b775b270400e7e61ed5cbc5a146ea70f53d5a3306ce02aaf97049cf181a and the storage entry I want to alter is the encoded storage key 0x1da53b775b270400e7e61ed5cbc5a146ea70f53d5a3306ce02aaf97049cf181a00e3fb4132e170c43b2c383560bbe9c8a4fd75a487b9e043e068dfc21acdc62b0b2ddaf0 retrieved by Polkadot JS Apps.

When calling system.setStorage(0x1da53b775b270400e7e61ed5cbc5a146ea70f53d5a3306ce02aaf97049cf181a00e3fb4132e170c43b2c383560bbe9c8a4fd75a487b9e043e068dfc21acdc62b0b2ddaf0, $NEW_VALUE) now,

neither the encoded partial storage key nor the encoded storage key can be decoded in Polkadot JS Apps. Only when reading raw storage, my desired valued is returned:
Picture: The storage entry cannot be decoded

Picture: Raw reading works though

What went wrong here? Did I use system.setStorage incorrectly? Do I need to provide another storage key other than the one printed by Polkadot Js Apps? Please help!

The key is correct. The inquiry revolves around the value. How did you get the 0xdeadbeef value? You can check it against the original value to ensure the byte lengths match. Additionally, I recommend using Rust to encode the value and print the output.

The 0xdeadbeef was of course just chosen here as an example. The hex of the real value was indeed crafted using Rust. Do I need encode it before calling setStorage?

You still haven't said how you obtained it. However, it is true that the value needs to be encoded.

Sorry that I have left out that part because it is just business logic. The value refers to the compiled byte-code of a solidity contract. I just wanted to override the value of the unchanged key which lead to the above issue. It doesn't make sense to me why it failed. I had to write a migration to recover the pallet_evm::AccountCodes storage. Even after I cleared it entirely and just set this one value, it failed to decode.

SCALE encode the value. You are setting a vector/array of bytes, so you have to prepend the length of the vector as a compact integer. Here your value 0xdeadbeef should be 0x10deadbeef
